# bin file unavailable in Apache Drill

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, cloud, cluster, configure

I installed Drill according to [Drill Documentation](https://drill.apache.org/docs/drill-in-10-minutes/#installation-overview). I have java installed. These are the steps I followed

1. `wget http://apache.mirrors.hoobly.com/drill/drill-1.16.0/apache-drill-1.16.0-src.tar.gz`
2. Then I extracted the folder by `tar -xvzf <.tar.gz file name>`
3. Then I go into the apache installation folder by `cd cd apache-drill-1.16.0`
4. Then the documentation asks to run this command `bin/drill-embedded`

The problem is that there is no bin folder inside the Apache Drill folder. 
Mentioned below are all the files found inside the Apache Drill installation Folder.

`DEPENDENCIES, LICENSE, README.md, contrib, docs, drill-yarn, git.properties, logical, protocol, src, KEYS,NOTICE, common, distribution, drill-shaded, exec, header, pom.xml, sample-data, tools`

How is it possible to run Apache Drill with the lack of a bin file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the Drill Documentation links us to download a src file.

Downloading from `http://apache.mirrors.hoobly.com/drill/drill-1.16.0/apache-drill-1.16.0.tar.gz` solved the issue. It had a bin folder. And I was able to run Apache Drill successfully.